# How to import web3 into pyscript?

Tags: python, web3py, pyscript

Im new to pyscript and i wan to use web3.py in my index page

This here is my index.html page

```
<body>
   
   <py-env>
      - web3
   </py-env>
 <py-script >
   import web3

   bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'    
   web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
   print(web3.isConnected())
 </py-script>

</body>
```

When I run this file the page is only loading but nothing is being displayed on my site.

I have installed web3 and I have tried to import it as

```
<py-env>
      - web3==5.30.0
   </py-env>
```

same error as above

Comment: Hello @Android, and welcome to StackOverflow! You mentioned "same error as above". What do you mean by the error? Do you mean that nothing was displayed on the page? Also, I believe that pyscript is still under active development, and socket (and therefore perhaps Web3) doesn't work because of restrictions of running things on the web.

Answer (score 2):

The package `web3` is not compatible with PyScript because the package depends on `websockets` which is not a pure Python 3 wheel and cannot be loaded by pyodide.

Any package that depends upon the TCP Sockets I/O APIs is not supported within a browser due to sandbox security limitations.

The solution is to ask the `web3` team to update their package, or perhaps do the updates yourself and contribute the changes.

Comment: can't we just run JS methods (to extract Metamask accounts and so on) then use normal python codes on our machine using pyscript?

Comment: @Anonymous - please create a new question.

Comment: I wrote it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633342/how-to-request-eth-requestaccounts-in-pyscript

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could help me. Also, regarding your answer, If one needs to use web3 I think it would be possible to use flask with PyScript. Where web3 could be run from the server side (I think) and PyScript could run for the front-end side.

Comment: @Anonymous - if you need help, create a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask