# How to send "eth_requestAccounts" to Metamask in PyScript?

Tags: python, request, ethereum, metamask, pyscript

I am trying to get address from installed MetaMask on the browser. We used to do this in JS as follow:

```
  const T1 = async () => {
    let Address = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    });
    accountChangeHandler(Address.toString());

    //   console.log(Address.toString());
  };
```

or

```
let balance = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_getBalance",
        params: [address, "latest"],
      });
```

In PyScript, I know we could import js module and use window.ethereum but I am not sure how to send requests with methods. I am aware of [pyfetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters).

I am failing to see how I could import address or send transactions same as we use to do in JS.

I wrote this PyScript code:

```
from js import document, alert, window, console
from pyodide import create_proxy
from pyodide.http import pyfetch
import asyncio


document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Click the button to check Metamask"


async def Check_if_Metamask(param):
    if not window.ethereum:
        alert("install metamask")
    else:
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Metamask is already installed"
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Welcome!"
        # console.log(window.ethereum.request)
        a = await window.ethereum.request(
            {
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            }
        )
        Address = await pyfetch(a, method="Get")
        output = Address
        console.log(output)
        console.log("This is a")
        console.log(a)


def setup():
    # Create a JsProxy for the callback function
    click_proxy = create_proxy(Check_if_Metamask)
    # Set the listener to the callback
    e = document.getElementById("submit-button2")
    e.addEventListener("click", click_proxy)


setup()
```

and the associated HTML is as follow

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Button Event Proxy</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Illustration 2/pyscript.css" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./buttoncss.css" />
    <script defer src="../Illustration 2/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="status">Check Metamask!</div>
    <br />
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <br />
    <button class="button-17" id="submit-button2">check</button>

    <py-script src="./code.py"> </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would put the second example into a JavaScript function and then call that function from PyScript. In JavaScript name the function `getBalance()`. Then call the function from PyScript: `js.getBalance()`. Don't forget to import the JavaScript namespace `import js` or `from js import getBalance`.

Comment: @JohnHanley how do I call JavaScript functions from pyscript? Any resources or references please.

Comment: I showed how in my comment `js.getBalance()`. I wrote almost 20 articles on how to use PyScript. I wrote one on JavaScrypt interop: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/category/pyscript/

Comment: @JohnHanley I learned pyscript from your articles :)

Comment: I should thank you :) @Anonymous commented on one of my answer for this question so  Last night i got so curious to solve this. whatever I typed any search key to google, it was showing me your articles. I saw your comments today and I was so surprised to see the owner of the articles

Comment: @JohnHanley and Yilmaz I want to thank both of you as I am learning from both of you a lot! Many thanks for this support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling javascript functions on DOM from `pyscript` we have to create a proxy and set it as our callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="connect" style="color:blue" >Connect</button> 
    <py-script>
      from js import alert, window,console,document
      # since sending request to metamask async we need this
      import asyncio
      from pyodide import create_proxy
      if not window.ethereum: 
        alert("install metamask")
      if window.ethereum:
        button = document.querySelector("button")
        # you need to pass "event" arg even though you do not use it. Otherwise it will throw this error
        # TypeError: request_eth() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
        async def request_eth(event):   
          try:
            await window.ethereum.request(method="eth_requestAccounts")
          except Exception as e:
            console.log(e)
        function=create_proxy(request_eth)
        button.addEventListener("click", function,False)   
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```